# I wish to make my Google sheet slightly easier for me to use

Tags: google-sheets

Can anyone teach me how to autofill the "Selling At" column `E` and "SC Used Per Transaction" when I key in the "Denomination Sold" Column?

So for example, when I key in "3688" under the "Denomination Sold", "2470" will appear under "SC Used Per Transaction" and the number "$65" will automatically appear under the "Selling At" Cell `E8`.

Another example if the above is unclear:
When I key in "86" at Cell `A14`, "62.5" will appear on Cell `B14` and "$1.90" will appear at Cell `E14` automatically.

I need it for every number from Cells `H10:H31` to match the Cells `J10:J31` and Cells `K10:K31`.

I do not need the "SC Cost" to autofill as it will change frequently and I am going to key that in myself.

Could anyone kindly please guide me through this?

If you do not understand my question, please fill free to ask.

[image: Spreadsheet Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this formula in cell `E9` for values from column `K`:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A9:A21,H10:K31,4,0)))
```

In a similar way use the following in cell `B9` for values from `J` column

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A9:A21,H10:K31,3,0)))
```

*(Just remember to clear everything in ranges affected by the formulas before applying them and as always, DO adjust formulas according to your ranges and locale)*

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)